# How to show progress indicator in System Tray for few seconds without using await [Windows Phone 8]

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

Every time when a user opens my app, the app needs to check that does it need to upload/download data to/from windows azure or not. However, if the user doesn't have internet connection, the app will show a last update time in System Tray. The app gets the last update time from SQLite which doesn't need to use await method to do it. So, how can I last the text in System tray for few seconds before it will be faded out.

This is my code

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SessionManagement.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            var userLastestPoopDataInSQLite = new SQLiteFunctions().GetUserPoopData(SessionManagement.GetEmail());
            if (userLastestPoopDataInSQLite.Count != 0)
            {
                userLastestpoopRecordInSqlite = userLastestPoopDataInSQLite.Last();
                if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
                {
                    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
                    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = GetLastUpdatedTimeInText(userLastestpoopRecordInSqlite.Date_Time);
                    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isUpdateNeeded = DateTime.Compare(userLastestpoopRecordInSqlite.Date_Time, userLastestPoopRecordInAzure.Date_Time);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Lastest time in Sqlite" + userLastestpoopRecordInSqlite.Date_Time);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Lastest time in azure" + userLastestPoopRecordInAzure.Date_Time);
                    Debug.WriteLine(isUpdateNeeded);
                    if (isUpdateNeeded == 0)
                    {
                        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
                        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Data is up-to-date";
                        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userLastestPoopDataInAzure = await new AzureFunctions().GetUserPoopDataInAzure(SessionManagement.GetEmail());
                        userLastestPoopRecordInAzure = userLastestPoopDataInAzure.Last();
                        StartSyncUserLastestData();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in support for showing the progress bar a limited time, so you will probably need to use a timer for this:

```
SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Data is up-to-date";

DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
{
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
    timer.Stop();
};

timer.Start();
```